# Chaining multiple combine_first()

Tags: python, pandas

What would be a better way to chain multiple combine_first() statements. 
i.e.

I have parsed some data, and have 3 different columns for cc-email. This works, but is there a cleaner way of doing it?

```
df['cc-email2'] = df['cc-email'].combine_first(
df['cc-email_cc-email'].combine_first(
df['cc-emails_cc-email']))
```

e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([])
df['cc-email'] = ('bob@hotmail.com', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan)
df['cc-email_cc-email'] = (np.nan, 'michael@outlook.com', np.nan, np.nan)
df['cc-emails_cc-email'] = ('bob@yahoo.com', np.nan, np.nan, 'trey@gmail.com')
```

Resultant df:

```
     cc-email           cc-email_cc-email   cc-emails_cc-email    cc-email2
0    bob@hotmail.com    NaN                 bob@yahoo.com         bob@hotmail.com
1    NaN                michael@outlook.com NaN                   michael@outlook.com
2    NaN                NaN                 NaN                   NaN
3    NaN                NaN                 trey@gmail.com        trey@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I  think you can use `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df['cc-email'], df['cc-email_cc-email'], df['cc-emails_cc-email']]
df['cc-email2'] = reduce(lambda l,r: l.combine_first(r), dfs)
```

But it seems `ffill` with select last column should working too:

```
df['cc-email2'] = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
print (df)
          cc-email    cc-email_cc-email cc-emails_cc-email  \
0  bob@hotmail.com                  NaN      bob@yahoo.com   
1              NaN  michael@outlook.com                NaN   
2              NaN                  NaN                NaN   
3              NaN                  NaN     trey@gmail.com   

             cc-email2  
0        bob@yahoo.com  
1  michael@outlook.com  
2                  NaN  
3       trey@gmail.com
```

Comment: the reduce method is definitely a better way to go about it, especially with a list comprehension. But I like the ffill idea (although I would need to rearrange the column orders)